# How to create new table in magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

I want to create my custom table in my custom module. how to create it in Magento 2.3. Is there any other way of install schema? I know for magento 1.9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create table for custom module in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647741/how-to-create-table-for-custom-module-in-magento)

Comment: that is for magento 1 and i asked for magento 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, create `db_schema.xml` file inside `/Vendor/Module/etc` and write the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="comment_here">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="column_name" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="column_name" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="column_name" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="column_name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Descrition"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

- `<table> .. </table>` = "Use for create and set table name"
- `<column> .. </column>` = "Use for create and set column of the table"
- `<constraint> .. </constraint>` = "Use for set constraint as like
  primary key, foreign key, unique key etc."

Before running the upgrade command you need to add your schema to `db_whitelist_schema.json` file by running the following command :

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=vendor_module
```

Now, there are db_whitelist_schema.json file will be create in `/vendor/module/etc` folder.

Answer (score 1):

From magento 2.3 their is new way of installing schema. You have to create new xml file in etc/db_schema.xml for installing schema.

for more detail please check the file at vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/db_schema.xml